# Swagger client problem: is the service producing inconsistent JSON/XML or am I doing something wrong?

Tags: java, json, xml, swagger, openapi

I am trying to consume a third party web service which uses Swagger, it purports to produce both XML and JSON.

Great, I'm hoping that I can just point the **swagger-codegen-maven-plugin** at the **swagger.json**, turn the handle and produce a client.

However, when I run a simple query with my generated code the resulting object is empty.  When I enable debugging I can see that the query is producing a response from the web service but it isn't being mapped into the list inside my model class.

The swagger documentation shows how to run it in both JSON and XML modes.

**XML** looks like:

```
curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/xml' 'https://blah/renderings'
```

(security omitted)
which produces something like:

```
<renderings xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="blahschema.xsd">
  <rendering>standard</rendering>
</renderings>
```

**JSON** looks like:

```
curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' 'https://blah/renderings'
```

which produces something like:

```
{
  "rendering": [
    "standard",
  ]
}
```

**The above looks wrong to me?**  With my limited understanding of JSON I believe this is "unwrapped" however,  I was expecting the data array to be called "*renderings*" in the JSON version - that appears to be the name inside the code generated model class anyway (for example, with the okhttp-gson client "renderings" is specified in the @SerializedName annotation).

As far as I can tell the following is the relevant part of the swagger.json.

> ```
> "WSRenderingsList" : {
>   "type" : "object",
>   "properties" : {
>     "renderings" : {
>       "type" : "array",
>       "xml" : {
>         "name" : "rendering"
>       },
>       "items" : {
>         "type" : "string",
>         "xml" : {
>           "name" : "rendering"
>         }
>       }
>     }
>   },
>   "xml" : {
>     "name" : "renderings"
>   }
> },
> ```

**Am I doing something wrong or is the service producing inconsistent results?**

Alternatively how can I specify in my Swagger code generation that I want to access the XML data in preference to the JSON version?

It is a multifarious web service, I'd rather ***not*** hand craft the client if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

I have contacted the supplier and they have agreed that the issue is with their web service.